# How can i get HWND of external application's listview? In Windows Api using c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

So i am trying to make app to get content of my explorer listviews and get item text etc.. from it but here are the problems...

If i inspect windows explorer folder(using spy++) with listview, just for testing purposes i will use random folder.

It shows me that caption of the window is "FolderView" with class "SysListView32" and the top level window where this listview is nested is called "reference", this is also the title of windows explorer folder where all the files are.

So what i do is..

```
HWND hWndLV = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("reference")); // first i get hwnd of the main window, this is where listview window is also nested according to spy++, thats why i do this first.

HWND child = FindWindowEx(hWndLV, NULL,NULL,TEXT("FolderView")); // trying to get hwnd of the listview here but it fails, same happens if i also put the class name along as 

HWND child = FindWindowEx(hWndLV, NULL,TEXT("SysListView32"),TEXT("FolderView"));
```

I am using `bool test = IsWindow(child);` to test for fail, also VS debugger shows `0x0000000000` each time so i am sure i am reading results well.

So i am stuck on this probably simple thing for most of people:(

p.s. i am on vista64(if that matters anyhow)

edit: It appears that this function works only if i search the first nested level of a parent window i am searching. So i assume what i need is a way to get handle with some sort of deep nested level search.

I also tried to go step by step by defining hwnd of every parent then i use findwindowex on it but oh boy then i get to the point where there are 5 nested windows all with the same name and only one of them contains my listview, so nice uh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you got a handle to main window (using `FindWindow` for example), you can enumerate its child windows using [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you please post some example how would i get a listview handle using EnumChildWindows, i am really new to this

Comment: @Marko29 An example you can find here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/01/16/1478717.aspx

Comment: I get the general idea how this works but now only thing i am puzzled about is how to grab the hwnd that i need(listview) while it enumerates trough it

Comment: BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

 cout << "hwnd_Child = " << hwnd << endl;
     return TRUE; 
}

Comment: got this to enumerate but all i get is hexadec number from every hwnd, how do i get the name of the one i want?

Comment: OK, if you got a HWND of the window, it shouldn't be a problem to obtain some other information about it. You can obtain a window class, and that's all you need. About windows classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574(v=VS.85).aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632596(v=VS.85).aspx ; using window classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633575(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I guess you like to torture me VLadimir, believe me its not so useful to just read bunch of class info there but thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Sorry Marko, I didn't want to torture you :)  Anyway, using function GetClassName you're able to obtain a class name. The last link I posted in previous comment is an example and following it you'll be able to find out which parameters are used in WNDCLASSEX structure (class name is just one of them). So, to simplify: assuming that you enumerated windows and retreiving HWND in a callback procedure - pass that HWND to GetClassName and you'll obtain the name of the window's class and identify it.